# Is there a way to pass debug secrets to a docker container from a asp.net console application using generic host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2017

I am setting up a new Docker container in asp.net using Visual Studio and usersecrets.  How do I access the usersecrets when debugging from within the container?

Container is a linux container that is hosting a generic service, it works fine if I provide the appsettings.json file but it will not populate information form secrets.json.  As a side note I did get it to work with a standard asp.net console app.

I have poured through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows to no avail.

I also looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2 page as well.

Nothing seems to point to using them with a docker container.

```
  `var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
    {
      configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
      configHost.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
      configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");

      if (args != null)
      {
        configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
      }

    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
      config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);

      if(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
      {
        config.AddUserSecrets<SecretStuff>();
      }
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
      services.Configure<SecretStuff> (hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SecretStuff)));
      services.Configure<ProcessFileSettings>(hostContext.Configuration);
      services.AddScoped<Interfaces.IFileUploader, WebClients.FileUploader>();
      services.AddHostedService<FolderLookupHostedService>();
    });

  await builder.RunConsoleAsync();'
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of my co-workers we found the solution.

You need to add a volumes value to the docker-compose.yml file that points to the usersecrets location.

```
volumes:
  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

When you add Container Orchestrator Support, Visual Studio 2017 does not add the volume line to the generated compose file in the Console App (.Net Core) project, it does in a ASP.NET Core Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/src/PathHelper.cs#L59-L67) from the .NET's GitHub repository, it appears that the path for user secrets in a Docker container should be `/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets`. You should specify the path as follows:

```yaml
volumes:
   - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works this solution:

```
volumes:    
       - server-path-to-secrets/secret.json:/home/.microsoft/usersecrets/secret.json:ro
```